# Is there a way to read a csv file find a null value at a specific index and write a new value to the null index?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read a file if there is a empty string value at index[7] i want to write a date value in place of the empty string. I want to do this at only specific index's on huge csv files up to 20GB csv files.

I have already tried writing to the file at the specific index[7] using a for loop but I keep getting object is not iterable.

```
import csv

text = '1970-01-01'

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[7] in (None, ""):
        //instead of print(text) cant i just write text to the csv 
        file?    
        print(text)

with open('file.csv', "wb") as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,  delimiter=',')
        for row in csvwriter:
            if row[7] in (None, ""):
                csvwriter.writerow([row[7], text])

error object is not iterable.
```

csv file example

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,ok,test

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,ok,test

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2019-01-01,ok,test

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,ok,test

I expect the empty ,, to be '1970-01-01' after i read and write to the file.

the results should end up being.

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1970-01-01,ok,test

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1970-01-01,ok,test

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2019-02-10,ok,test

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1970-01-01,ok,test

Comment: I added the error and write statement i have been trying but i keep getting an error

Comment: For anyone trying to figure out how to do this I found an excellent solution

   ` import csv
    import os
    import shutil


    def update_filenames(filename, list_of_indexes):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        with open('new.csv', 'w') as new_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

            for row in csv_reader:
                for i in list_of_indexes:
                    if row[i] in (None, ""):
                        row[i] = '1970-01-01'
                csv_writer.writerow(row) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution for anyone that wants to try to do something like this**

```
import csv
import os
import shutil


def update_filenames(filename, list_of_indexes):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        with open('new.csv', 'w') as new_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

            for row in csv_reader:
                for i in list_of_indexes:
                    if row[i] in (None, ""):
                        row[i] = '1970-01-01'
                csv_writer.writerow(row)

    shutil.move('new.csv', filename)

filename_indexes = [7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 24, 25, 27]
update_filenames('filename.csv', filename_indexes)
```